# ArcGIS Server running in different clusters?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, server, license

I´m looking at different configurations of ArcGIS Server 10.2.1 and I can´t understand the installation of ArcGIS Server running in diferent clusters.

Is it only a configuration setting that use the resource of the machine or is it necessary for different machines servers with one license for each machine?

With the answer of Vince, is this correct?

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify which version of ArcGIS you are using, and how many servers you have licensed.  Clustering is not possible with a single node.

Comment: Thanks Vince, I´ve added the version number but for the number of the servers is a part of the question, I think that perhaps the question would be: How works ArcGIS Server running in different cluster?

Comment: ESRI has a vast Help resources. Have you really checked their manuals? These resources might help you: http://video.arcgis.com/watch/1519/ds2011-architecting-arcgis-server-to-scale http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//015400000418000000

Comment: I don't understand your edit. If you structure  your English in shorter sentences, your meaning might be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple meanings of "cluster", and I fear you may be confusing them...

In ArcGIS Server 10.1+ parlance, a "cluster" is a bound subset of servers within an ArcGIS Server site.  The [documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/0154/015400000418000000.htm) contains this image, which shows how a subset of servers can be allocated to one aspect of GIS services.

[image: cluster from doc]

In this diagram there are three (3) hosts running ArcGIS Server, all bound in one (1) site, with two (2) clusters  (one for mapping services, and one for geoprocessing). Depending on the characteristics of the nodes (CPU cores & RAM), and the frequency  of requests, this site could serve dozens or scores or hundreds of clients.

There are other ways to allocate services across servers, but clusters provide a convenient way to organize allocation of services to hosts in a large enterprise configuration.

In practice, you need to be careful to not have too many nodes in a single cluster, lest their internal communication impact overall throughput.

All of the nodes on which ArcGIS Server services are running must be licensed for ArcGIS.

Comment: I´m editing my question with your picture thanks Vince